# HTTP Post sent from Java

Tags: java, http

Worldpay (The payment processor from RBS) sends a HTTP Post to my website once a payment is accepted. Problem is - the Post isnt getting through and my server responds with one of the following 3 HTTP error's:

HTTP 408 (Timeout)
HTTP 405 (Not allowed)
Invalid status line >NULL<

Now when i Post something to the url from my test php script this works fine which leads me to believe the issue could be with the fact that the Post from them is created by Java:

```
POST /worldpay_success.html HTTP/1.0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Host: www.mysite.com
Content-Length: 116
User-Agent: WJHRO/1.0 (WorldPay Java HTTP Request Object)

authAmountString=%26%23163%3B1.99&_SP.charEnc=UTF-8&desc=Test.....etc
```

Does anyone have any experience with this? After speaking to Worldpay they say my server is responding with a 408 Timeout after 0.1 seconds so it doesnt seem to be properly timeing out... Any help apreciated

Paul

Comment: Just making sure...Are they sending GET parameters in POST request or am I just misinterpreting this?

Comment: Not sure about the *408*, but *405* seems like either they are not sending it as a POST request or your server requires a different request method.

Comment: Just a thought, maybe run a packet sniffer like wireshark or something so that you can see their actual packet they send. Do the same for the packet that you're generating and compare.

Answer (score 1):

Check [405 Method Not Allowed](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E405.html) and [Request Timeout](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E408.html). It shouldn't matter if the POST request is created from Java.

Comment: this is what i need to know. When i recreate the post request exactly and post to the same url from php there is no problem but when it is sent by them it wont get through... just no idea...